# Panels not appearing in Structure

Tags: 7, panels

This may be a fairly basic question, but I'm having a hard time getting the Panels module to show up in Structure after enabling it. CTools is enabled and I also tried enabling the Panels node module and the In-Place Editor, but still no luck. I'm running Drupal 7 and have tried clearing the cache.

Comment: If you're not on user 1, have you given permission to the user to 'Use Panels Dashboard'? Also try enabling the Page Manager sub-module in Chaos Tools.

Comment: This turned out to be a permissions issue, as you surmised. Thank you.